# How to move 2 cols 1 row into 1 col 2 rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a query which I cannot seem to get right. I want to change the result set so it is 1 column and can be N number of rows.

Original query

```
select src_approval, dst_approval
from example_table
where id = 62615
group by src_approval, dst_approval
```

I tried the following which is not correct.

```
select src_approval, dst_approval
from example_table
unpivot
( colvalue for col in (src_approval, dst_approval) )
where id = 62615
group by src_approval, dst_approval
```

I tried the following which still returns 2 columns:

```
select *
from   
    (select src_approval, dst_approval
     from example_table
     where id= 62615
     group by src_approval, dst_approval)
unpivot
    (income_component_value
         for income_component_type in (src_approval, dst_approval)
       )
```

**RESULT**

```
select *
from   ( 
select src_approval, dst_approval
from e_p
where exemption_id = 62615
group by src_approval, dst_approval
)
 unpivot
       ( owner
         for approval in (src_approval, dst_approval)
       )
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still use `unpivot` as

```
select colvalue from 
(
select id, colvalue, col
  from example_table   
  unpivot(colvalue for col in(src_approval,dst_approval))
)  
where id = 62615
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e42f2d4b4f9af184a5839020cd494c1)</kbd>

Comment: what is the difference between what you have and what i pasted as result?

Comment: In your first case for unpivot, the columns come from the paranthesed part after unpivot keyword(id, colvalue, col ), but not columns of the table. Indeed the second one should work @shorif2000 .

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering `unpivot`, you can use a lateral join:

```
select distinct x.dte
from example_table et cross join lateral
     (select et.src_approval as dte from dual union all
      select et.dst_approval as dte from dual
     ) x
where id = 62615;
```

More commonly, this would just be written using `union`:

```
select et.src_approval
from example_table et
union     -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select et.dst_approval
from example_table et;
```

Comment: which would be faster, as i would have millions of rows

Comment: the lateral join did not return any results

Comment: @shorif2000 . . . Does it return an error?  Otherwise the `where` clause filters all the values out.